# flutter UniqueKey cast to another type of data sqflite

Tags: flutter, casting, sqflite

I have a field in a class of type UniqueKey called "_id":

```
class RegistroAnsiedad{

  late final UniqueKey _id;
  late final int _estado_animo;
  late final int _fecha;
  late final int _nivel_ansiedad;
  late final int _actividad;

RegistroAnsiedad(
      this._estado_animo,
      this._fecha,
      this._nivel_ansiedad,
      this._actividad,
      [UniqueKey? id]
      ):this._id = id ?? UniqueKey();



  Map<String, Object?> toMap() {
    var mapa = <String, dynamic>{
      "_fecha": _fecha,
      "_nivel_ansiedad": _nivel_ansiedad,
      "_actividad": _actividad
    };
    if (id != null) {
      mapa["_id"] = _id;
    }
    return mapa;
  }

....
```

When I want to write a record of the above type in sqflite with the following code:

```
registro_ansiedad = RegistroAnsiedad(
          controlador_actividad.estado_animo.value,
          controlador_actividad.fecha.value,
          controlador_actividad.nivel_ansiedad.value,
          numero_actividad);

     //Se inserta el registro
      final int id_fila = await dbHelper.inserta(registro_ansiedad.toMap());
```

I get the following error:

**Invalid argument [#adc81] with type UniqueKey.
I/flutter ( 6002): Only num, String and Uint8List are supported.**

I know my mistake is trying to write a UniqueKey to Sqflite when it only supports integer, text, ...

How can I convert my UniqueKey field to integer or text?

Thank you in advance

Daniel Leyva

Answer (score 0):

I could use a autoincrement field and so I should not have to convert to UniqueKey